# Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

Tags: mysql, casting

When I run the following query:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED VIEW d_view_galerias AS (
SELECT id, titulo, 'foto' AS tipo, '' AS embed
FROM d_galeria_fotos
)
UNION (

SELECT id, titulo, 'video' AS tipo, embed
FROM d_galeria_videos
)
```

I get the error:

> Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

"tipo" is getting as utf8_unicode, but the other fields are as utf8_general ... how to make a cast, convert?

Answer (score 8):

The error message is rather confusing as it specifies `operation =` -- which  is not obvious from the query you posted but is caused by the `UNION` query which select only *distinct* values. So using implicitly an equality comparaison.

Anyway, you can always *force* the collation of a column using the [`COLLATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html) clause. Here is a an example, assuming you want to change the collation of the column `tipo`:

```
SELECT id, titulo, 'foto' COLLATE utf8_general_ci AS tipo

... 
UNION SELECT id, titulo, 'video' COLLATE utf8_general_ci AS tipo, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. What I did was to isolate the comparison in the where clause that's causing the error. I ran the [CONVERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-convert.html) function on the value I to compare with into the collation of the table.

```
`field` = CONVERT(value USING charset_of_table)
```

See [this post](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/convert.php) for more details and examples on using CONVERT

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Schema in my sql workbench, click on design icon. Change character set there. Error was gone in my case.